# Error 'No Error' when omitting assignment

Tags: variable-assignment, assignment-operator, apl

I am playing around with APL doing [this problem](http://projecteuler.net/problem=5).

I have defined the following functions:

```
∇ r ← smallestFactor n
    ⍝ Find smallest factor of n
    r ← (0 = r) + r ← 1 ↑ (0 = r | n) / r ← 1 ↓ ⍳ n
∇

∇ r ← factors n; sf
    ⍝ List of all prime factos of n, repeated according to their power
    r ← ⍳ 0
    → (1 = n) / 0
    r ← sf, factors n ÷ sf ← smallestFactor n
∇

∇ r ← c count iter
    ⍝ Count occurances of c in iter
    r ← +/ (c = iter) / 1
∇
```

Now when I execute the following, I get the expected result (232792560):

```
×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count facs ← factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20
```

But when I omit the assignment to `facs` it fails horribly:

```
×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20 

==============================================================================
Assertion failed: 0
in Function:      init
in file:          Cell.cc:47

Call stack:

----------------------------------------
-- Stack trace at Cell.cc:47
----------------------------------------
0x7f713e200ea5 __libc_start_main
0x4314dc  main
0x4f34bd   Workspace::immediate_execution(bool)
0x4545cd    Command::process_line()
0x452f26     Command::process_line(UCS_string&)
0x44030f      Bif_OPER2_PRODUCT::eoc_outer_product(Token&, _EOC_arg&)
0x43ffac       Bif_OPER2_PRODUCT::finish_outer_product(OUTER_PROD&)
0x44a309        Cell::init(Cell const&)
0x43c2ca         do_Assert(char const*, char const*, char const*, int)
========================================

SI stack:

Depth:    0
Exec:     0x9f3310
Pmode:    ◊  ×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20
PC:       12 /
Stat:     ×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20
err_code: 0x0
thrown:   at StateIndicator.cc:38
e_msg_1:  'No Error'
e_msg_2:  ''
e_msg_3:  ''


==============================================================================
*** immediate_execution() caught other exception ***
```

I am using GNU APL, so I don't have fancy dfuns.

I actually fail to see the difference between the two statements.

**Whence cometh this error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine without the assignment in Dyalog APL using your exact traditional function definition. Direct from the session:

```
     ×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count facs ← factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20
232792560
     ×/ twenty * ⌈/ twenty ∘.count factors ¨ twenty ← 1 ↓ ⍳ 20
232792560
```

Looks like it must be a bug in GNU APL.

Also, your expression for counting the occurances of c in iter can be simply written as:

```
r←+/c=iter
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the interpreter - I will look into it.

If you see interpreter output like the above mentioning "Assertion failed" or
showing stack dumps then this is always an internal error of the interpreter
and should be reported directly to bug-apl@gnu.org.

Jürgen

PS. should be fixed now, see latest version in SVN repository..